# Jquery Ui resizeable and draggable event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i disabled the draggable and resizable events on a box but once you use the disabled true attr it does disable the draggable and resizeable events but it reduces the opacity of the box as if it had an overlay.Does anyone know why that is?

```
$('#box').resizable({disabled:true});
 $('#box').draggable({disabled:true});
```

**box css:**

```
#box{ 
      position:absolute; 
      top:40px; 
      left:600px; 
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px; 
      border:1px solid #000; 
      background-color: #fff; 
   }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: can i see the html associated with the element #box????

Comment: The css #box{
    position:absolute;
   top:40px;
    left:600px;
   width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color: #fff;
  }

Comment: The html is just a div with the id box

Comment: That's what jQuery UI does if it is `disabled`. You'll have to probably `destroy` the `draggable` and re-create it when necessary.

Comment: yeap, its a default configuration this option

Comment: Oh thanks jack, i just read the documentation and i saw the destroy event. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destroy function worked

```
$('#box').draggable( "destroy" );
$('#box').resizable( "destroy" );
```